# Exundelete can't restore the file

Tags: centos, hard-disk, data-recovery, inode, extundelete

I'm trying to restore 2 important tar.gz files I know their directory but extundelete not restoring them although it's giving me the inode number.

```
Loading filesystem metadata ... 2127 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 26473 descriptors loaded.
Unable to restore inode 3538958 (file.tar.gz): No data found.
Unable to restore file file.tar.gz
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to examine filesystem
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to examine filesystem
```

And

```
Loading filesystem metadata ... 2127 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 26473 descriptors loaded.
Unable to restore inode 3538958 (file.tar.gz): No data found.
Unable to restore file file2.tar.gz
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to examine filesystem
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to examine filesystem
```

Is there a way to repair the inode or get the file?

Do you advice to use other recovering software for CentOS 6 64bit

Comment: All I can think of is that you need to be restoring to a writable partition and restoring from a partition that is not mounted. I don't think you can (I never could) restore from and to the same partition.

Answer (score 1):

Space used by deleted files is free, as far as the kernel is concerned. It is thus fair game for assigning to new files. If some piece got overwritten, it is very unlikely that you can recover the mangled file.

To have some probability of success, cease *all* activity on that filesystem as soon as possible, and run you recovery tool on it mounted read-only (writing somewhere else, obviously). If you only get parts of the file, you'd have to use tools to e.g. repair gzipped files or unpack damaged tar files.